# why geolocation in extjs can't get current location in mobile?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

all dear ,I want to that I can get current location web bower, but when test on really device like phone not get current location, hope that all dear have been meet the problem and help  me to solve the problem
                        xtype: 'map',
                        title:'CurrentLocation',
                        iconCls: 'fa fa-location-arrow',
                        layout: {type: 'fit'},
                       // iconCls : 'home',
                        mapOptions : { 
                            zoom: 17, 
                            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            disableDefaultUI: false,
                            zoomControl: true,
                            scrollwheel: true,
                            mapTypeControl: true,
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}

```
                        ,mapTypeControlOptions: {
                              style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU, mapTypeIds: [
                                 google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                 google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                                 google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
                              ]
                          }

                    },

                    useCurrentLocation  : true,
                    listeners           : {
                    maprender: function(comp, map){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position    : new google.maps.LatLng( ),
                        visible: true,
                        //map: map,
                        //draggable:true,
                        //icon:'resources/3.png',
                        animation:google.maps.Animation.Drop
                    }),
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content     : 'Your CurrentLocation'
                    }),
                    route = [ ],
                    geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
                        frequency         : 3000,
                        autoUpdate        : true,
                        allowHighAccuracy : true,
                        listeners         : {
                           /*initialize :function(geo) {
                                latitude=Global.currentUserLocations.currentLat;
                                longitude=Global.currentUserLocations.currentLong;
                                if(Global.currentUserPositionMarker)
                                {
                                    latlng1=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                    Global.currentUserPositionMarker.setPosition(latlng1);
                                }
                               }*/
                            locationupdate : function(geo) {
                                polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                    //console.info('polyline',polyline)
                                    path : route,
                                        strokeColor: '#2FCEE2',
                                        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                                        strokeWeight: 100,
                                        fillColor: 'red',
                                        fillOpacity: 1,
                                        //map: map,

                                });
                                polyline.setMap(map),

                                //alert(route);
                                route.push( new google.maps.LatLng( geo.getLatitude(),geo.getLongitude() ) );

                                marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng( geo.getLatitude(),geo.getLongitude() ) );

                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                     infowindow.open(map, marker);

                                });

                            }
                            // ,locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                            //     if(bTimeout){
                            //         alert('Timeout occurred.');
                            //     } else {l
                            //         alert('Error occurred.');
                            //     }
                            // }
                        } 
                    });
                    geo.updateLocation();

                    }
                 }
                }
```

Comment: is locationService in your phone enabled ??

Comment: xtype: 'map',
 title:'CurrentLocation',
 iconCls: 'fa fa-location-arrow',
 layout: {type: 'fit'},
mapOptions          : { 
     zoom: 17, 
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
disableDefaultUI: false,
zoomControl: true,
scrollwheel: true,
mapTypeControl: true,
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}